# why does c++ allow constant references to be initialized by a numeric value?

Tags: reference, constants, definition, numeric

Why does this work in c++? :

```
const int& a = 5;
```

A reference is an alias. Ideally, a reference declaration should not result in allocation of memory to any variable. However, try this:

```
cout<<&a<<endl;
```

You will get a memory address!
Instead, the following will do the same thing:
    const int a = 5;

while being more elegant.

Again, what is the use of such a statement:

```
const int& a = 5;
```

? And why is it allowed in c++?

Comment: to make reference constant? so it can be used in some array inits

Comment: I can see the utility of assigning numeric values, particularly pointer arithmetic. But you have a point - how would you know at compile-time what the memory address of a given resource would be?

Comment: A reference is still a variable and will allocate 8 bits to store an address of whatever you reference